# Custom JavaScript not working in Joomla 3 template

Tags: javascript, php, templates, joomla

i have problem with including javascript in joomla 3 template code. I am trying to create slider menu with http://9bitstudios.github.io/flexisel/. Outside of joomla with only html and java code, menu works great. But when i try to implement into joomla template i cant get it working.

My template code:

```
<?php 
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
   xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" >
<head>
    <jdoc:include type="head" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/general.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/reset.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/style.css" type="text/css" />



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/flexisel.css" type="text/css" />
    <?php
    JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/jquery.flexisel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(window).load(function() {
            $("#flexiselDemo1").flexisel();
        });
    </script>




</head>
<body>

    <div id="page">
        <div id="head">
            <a href="http://www.vossp.cz" class="logo">VOSSP</a>
        </div>
        <div id="main-menu">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="main-menu" /> 
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I tryed using of $document->addScriptDeclaration and $document->addScript, from http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript, but no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing jQuery in noConflict mode, so try changing this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#flexiselDemo1").flexisel();
});
```

to this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#flexiselDemo1").flexisel();
});
```

Note: go back to using `JHtml::_('jquery.framework');`

Comment: Still not working, i even tryed JHtml::_('jquery.framework', false);

Comment: @user3931028 - I've updated the code in my answer. It works perfectly fine with document ready